# Handlebars.js: Use a partial like it was a normal, full template

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, handlebars.js

I have a template that I want to use both as a partial, and by itself from javascript.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If your templates are precompiled, you can access your partials via `Handlebars.partials['partial-name']()` as well as call them from a template via the `{{> partial}}` helper.

This is nice because you can then write a utility function for rendering a template whether it be a full blown template or partial.

ex:

```
function elementFromTemplate(template, context) {
    context = context || {};
    var temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = templates[template] ? templates[template](context) : Handlebars.partials[template](context);
    return temp.firstChild;
}
```

`myDiv.appendChild(elementFromTemplate('myPartial', context));`

`myDiv.appendChild(elementFromTemplate('a-whole-template'));`

Hope this helps anyone else who wants to use Handlebars like I do.

Comment: Handlebars.partials[ 'partial-name' ] does not return a function though, it returns the template (a string). Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: @mynameistechno Probably because you aren't precompiling your templates (like you should be!)

Comment: This doesn't work if the partial contains table elements like `tr`. innerHTML won't parse the table elements into the temp div.

Answer (score 16):

It's easier to do it the other way around - to compile all your templates as normal templates, then make them available as partials:

```
Handlebars.partials = Handlebars.templates
```

This makes it possible to use your templates as usual, and as partials as well:

```
{{> normalTemplate}}
```

Comment: Interesting idea. Is there a downside or a reason you'd ever want partials that are not normal templates? (If not, it seems Handlebars could just use the `{{> xxx}}` syntax to mean include another template, and not have the partials concept at all?)

Comment: Exactly my thought. I don't understand the partials concept, and have yet to find a good reason to use them. I guess it's a convention thing? Or some kind of optimization... Which doesn't matter if you (and you should) precompile templates. I might be missing something, but with precompiling at least, this method seems safe.

Comment: Really interesting "hack", quite useful with pre-compiled templates indeed!

Answer (score 5):

To render a partial from javascript you can use

```
Handlebars.partials["myPartial"]()
```

Answer (score 2):

To use a partial from a template, simply include `{{> partialName}}`.

```
<script id="base-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div>
    {{> person}}  <!-- This is the partial template name -->
  </div>
</script>

<script id="partial-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="person">
    <h2>{{first_name}} {{last_name}}</h2>
    <div class="phone">{{phone}}</div>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var template = Handlebars.compile($("#base-template").html());

    //Aliasing the template to "person"
    Handlebars.registerPartial("person", $("#partial-template").html()); 

    template(yourData);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: And how would I render that partial from javascript (not in a template)?

Comment: Do you mean this -: el.html(this.template(yourData));

Comment: Just an fyi why this is not the accepted answer: This is all information that is easily found in Handlebar's documentation and is basic usage of a partial. I was fully aware of how to use a partial inside a template before asking the question, but it took some digging into Handlebar's source to learn how to render a partial directly from javascript.

Comment: I downvoted answer as it does not address the question