# JS templating engine that preserves elements

Tags: javascript, templates

I have the following problem:

A have a web application where I regularly need to update the user interface when data changes. The data consists of a list of items with different attributes. Because the UI representations of these items can be complex, I use JS templating to render them. When they change I just replace them in the DOM with the HTML representing their updated state.

This approach is simple but has several problems:

- you need to re-attach all event handlers because you practically replace elements
- there is a flickering effect when reloading resources (probably can be solved using document fragments)
- it's impossible to work with developer tools (inspector) if the content changes frequently because, again, all the elements are replaced

So I was wondering if there is any JS templating engine of [that many](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/) that can deal with the situation. I'm thinking of a feature that intelligently matches elements of the new render and an old one and only changes the content when it has really changed.

I'm thinking of something like this:

**Old HTML**

```
<div>
    <h1>TV</h1>
    <span>$250</span>
    <a href="addtocart?id=123">Add to cart</a>
</div>
```

**New HTML**

```
<div>
    <h1>TV</h1>
    <span>$260</span>
    <a href="addtocart?id=123">Add to cart</a>
</div>
```

The templating engine find the `<span>` in the original DOM and replaces its changed value but leaves the rest of the elements intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I came across [Rivets.js](http://rivetsjs.com/) which a lightweight, highly extensible JavaScript templating engine with real time data binding. I love it so far, it's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the AngularJS

A simple example:http://jsbin.com/opayuf/4/edit

you can check out these examples if they can meet your requirements
http://tutorialzine.com/2013/08/learn-angularjs-5-examples/

HandleBarsJs may be the one you need, you could see the discussion on
[Handlebars.js: Use a partial like it was a normal, full template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306382/handlebars-js-use-a-partial-like-it-was-a-normal-full-template)

You can also try Ember js based on HandlerBarsJs, you can check is out 
http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/handlebars-basics/

http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/

Comment: We have thought about Angular but we felt it's too heavy for our project and we really only looking for templating, not a whole frontend framework. Thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Comment: I think Handlebars js might be the option for you.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find any feature like this in Handlebars. Can you explain what you are thinking of? Thanks!

Comment: Use the handlebarjs to refresh the html, the data to be updated will depend on the ajax on some events.
Actually, the way you still have to use ajax or some other ways, not only use handlebarsJS to update data.